# Auto text box resize for illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cs6

I am wanting a similar option to Opt+command+C in illustrator CS6 I have seen the same question asked however I am using CS6 and when I go to Area type options auto resize option box to tick is not there.

[image]

Also have tried going into preferences as another tutorial suggested
https://millo.co/overlooked-illustrator-feature-first-now-saves-time-headaches
But also the auto type resize box to tick is not there.

[image]

Comment: It's interesting you chose to mark the "correct" answer as one that explains how to use **point text** rather than **area text**. It's not a big deal, but "use point text"  ultimately does not answer the posed question in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although what Scott suggested is true, you may find this helpful. When trying to create a text box to write in, *instead of clicking and dragging to create the box*, having selected the **Type Tool** from the toolbox, try *just clicking and then starting to write*. Please tell me if this worked for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Creative Suite 6 (CS6) applications do **not** have all the features of more recent Adobe releases.

The autosize area type option is not there in Illustrator CS6 and there's no way to force it to be there. The feature is only available from Adobe in newer releases of the application.

In fact, your links *specifically* states.... "As of CC 2014.1..."